# Add xml dynamically to layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a (complex) RelativeLayout with a few TextViews, ImageViews and a Button. The amount of how often this layout is created depends on data from the database. I get this data from a list and want to show it dynamically, what have I to do?

xml to add dynamically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/zusatz_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum 1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/button_desc" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ima_zusatz_desc"
    android:src="@drawable/nix" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum 2" />
```

Notice: The texts and image should be changed dynamically by the content from the database.

thanks, tomtom

Comment: not clear what you are asking.

Comment: how to add those xml layout to a parent layout programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Besides your XML, you will need an Adaptor and a ListView of some kind. In your Adapter you will have to implement

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

In this method, return your new view (Probably created with LayoutInflator and your xml) and update that data displayed on each button/text view.

Make sure to research how convertView works. If your lists are long, the performance boost from using convertView properly is huge. If you get this correct, Android's listview and baseadpater will do the hard work for you.